# AngularJS - Minifying modules with gulp

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, gulp

I am trying to set up a structure so I can minify/uglify all of my angular code.

I tried to copy the angular module structure from the [Angle Bootstrap Theme](http://themicon.co/theme/angle/v3.3.1/backend-angular/#/app/documentation)

It works fine when all the unmified js files are loaded but when I try to minify all it ends up not finding the modules.

I am getting this error: `[$injector:nomod] Module 'app.core' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

This is a MVC 5.2.3 project and the structure of the angular files are like this:

```
Scripts/angular/app.module.js
Scripts/angular/modules/core/core.config.js
Scripts/angular/modules/core/core.module.js
Scripts/angular/modules/module1/module1.controller.js
Scripts/angular/modules/module1/module1.module.js
```

So app.module.js looks like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp', [
            'app.core',
            'app.module1',
            ...
        ]);
})();
```

core.config.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core')
        .config(coreConfig);

    coreConfig.$inject = ['$controllerProvider', '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide', '$animateProvider'];
    function coreConfig($controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $animateProvider) {

        var core = angular.module('app.core');
        core.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
        core.directive = $compileProvider.directive;
        core.filter = $filterProvider.register;
        core.factory = $provide.factory;
        core.service = $provide.service;
        core.constant = $provide.constant;
        core.value = $provide.value;

        core.config(function (paginationTemplateProvider) {
            paginationTemplateProvider.setPath(window.rootUrl + 'scripts/plugins/angular-pagination/dirPagination.tpl.html');
        });

        $animateProvider.classNameFilter(/^((?!(ng-no-animation)).)*$/);
    }

})();
```

core.module.js:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core', [
            'ngSanitize',
            'ngRoute',
            'ngAnimate',
            'ngResource',
            'ngStorage',
            'ui.bootstrap'
        ]);
})();
```

And all the modules have this structure:

module1.controller.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.note')
        .controller('module1', module1);

    module1.$inject = ['$scope', '$localStorage'];
    function module1($scope, $localStorage) {
        .....
    };
})();
```

and the module1.module.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.module1', []);
})();
```

gulpfile.js

```
/// <binding Clean='clean' />
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

var paths = {
    webroot: "./"
};


paths.js = paths.webroot + "scripts/angular/**/*.js";
paths.minJs = paths.webroot + "scripts/angular/**/*.min.js";

..

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

..
```

Comment: Is core.module imported before app.module?

Comment: Hmm not sure what you mean. I can add the gulpfile aswell.

Comment: So the only file I am adding in my view is the minfied file from gulp.

Comment: Im not to familiar with gulp.. at a guess I would imagine that app.module is being minified and concatenated before core.module which is creating the issue. Try altering your gulp.src to minify and then concatenate in logical order starting with core.module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably is an order problem.

You have a good naming conventio so you can order your input stream taking the *.module.js files first.

you have to include

```
var order = require("gulp-order");
```

than after the gulp.src you have to order your input the risult should be likethis

```
gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(order([
            '**/*.module.js',
            '**/*.js'
        ]))
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

as you can see the order take an array of pattern.

Maybe the pattern are not perfect for your case but it should work.

hope this helps